# Increase android minimumSdk in react-native

Tags: java, android, react-native

So i have a native android view in my react-native app, but this native view use a minsdk = 18, and i get errors even using

```
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="library.pckg.etc"/>
```

and updating the manifest tag to use it i get this error

```
AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
```

How can i increase my react-native app minSdk to build succesfully my app?
Until now i tried to increase the values in build.gradle files and manifest but i keep getting this error when i run react-native run-android.

Comment: Try building the project from the android studio and update the question with the error if there is some other error found.

Comment: You can update your minSdkVersion from your app's build.gradle from your android studio.

Comment: I already updated the minsdk in build.gradle and manifest as i said, @Codesingh same errors, just 1 warning more for a conflict with version dependency, but even fixing that warning i get the same errors, 4 of (almost) the same type, it change just the resource name, i tried to delete those strings for the resource name but when i run the build gradle recreate those strings